# Using VLC as RTSP server

Tags: vlc-media-player, video-streaming, rtsp

I'm trying to figure out how to use the server capabilities of VLC. More specifically, how to export an SDP file when RTP streaming. In [chapter 4](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch04.html) in the section related to RTP Streaming examples for server and client are given:

```
vlc -vvv input_stream --sout '#rtp{dst=192.168.0.12,port=1234,sdp=rtsp://server.example.org:8080/test.sdp}'
vlc rtsp://server.example.org:8080/test.sdp
```

It's not very clear to me how to make it actually work. I have tried these two commands for server and client using two cmd instances:

```
vlc -I rc screen:// --sout=#rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=4444,sdp=rtsp://localhost:8080/test.sdp} 
vlc -I rc rtsp://localhost:8080/test.sdp
```

Invoking the second command causes the first one to crash. The second command shows the error message "could not connect to localhost:8080".

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that most likely the example you're looking at is for streaming a file and your example command is using the `screen://` input.  To make the `screen://` device work you need to encode the video first.  So try something like this:

```
vlc -I rc screen:// --sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=800,scale=0.25,fps=10}:rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=4444,sdp=rtsp://localhost:8080/test.sdp}
vlc -I rc rtsp://localhost:8080/test.sdp
```

Comment: When I run this command I get main stream out error: no sout stream module matched "transcodefps=10" main stream output error: stream chain failed for `transcodefps=10:rtpsdp=rtsp://localhost:8080/test.sdp'    What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the command exactly as its given?  If not what is the command you're using?

Comment: Running it exactly as given.   $ vlc -I rc screen:// --sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=800,scale=0.25,fps=10}:rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=4444,sdp=rtsp://localhost:8080/test.sdp}
VLC media player 1.0.6 Goldeneye
Remote control interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
[0x98ad010] main stream out error: no sout stream module matched "transcodefps=10"
[0x98ac8b0] main stream output error: stream chain failed for `transcodefps=10:rtpsdp=rtsp://localhost:8080/test.sdp'
[0x98a5cb0] main input error: cannot start stream output instance, aborting

Answer (score 4):

You need to double quote the command

```
--sout="#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=800,scale=0.25,fps=10}:rtp{dst=127.0.0.1,port=444‌​4,sdp=rtsp://localhost:8080/test.sdp}"
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Nothing happens.